# What is the probability of described batch qualifying though inspection?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Pins are made in batches of 200 units. From each batch, 6 pins are randomly chosen for inspection. If none of these 6 pins are faulty, the batch of 200 is sent to a customer. One customer received a batch that contained 15 faulty pins. What is the probability of described (faulty) batch qualifying through inspection?

...ok, so do I have to assume a probability for a faulty pin? I can't seem to realize how to go forward without one.

Answer (score 0):

If you only inspect one unit in that batch,the possibility for qualifying is 15/200.
If you inspect two, it will be 15/200*15/199.
And so on.
So the answer for fifteen faulty pin to be qualified is 15/200*14/199*13/198*12/197*11/196*10/195=
10*11*12*13*14*15/200*199*198*197*196*195

Answer (score 0):

It says that the batch had 15 faulty pins out of 200, so it had 185 pins that are fine. So when uniformly randomly choosing 6 out of the 200 pins without replacement (meaning you choose 6 different pins), the probability of choosing 6 non-faulty ones and qualifying is

$\Pr(\text{all 6 non faulty}) = \frac{185}{200}\cdot \frac{184}{199}\cdot \frac{183}{198}\cdot\frac{182}{197}\cdot \frac{181}{196}\cdot \frac{180}{195}$